# decompiling dll files for ASP

Tags: dll, asp-classic

I have a DLL file that Issue use with ASP. In need to decompile the DLL file in order too modify it to suite my needs.

I need anyone to guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Decompilers

[Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

I used the one from reflector, it worked really good

Comment: It seems Reflector is just for dotnet assemblies. It gives an error when opening a non-dotnet dll. (like old asp codes)